# read 2 bytes in hexadecimal base and convert into decimal using C language fscanf

Tags: c, hex, byte, scanf

Well as said Im using C language and fscanf for this task but it seems to make the program crash each time then its surely that I did something wrong here, I havent dealed a lot with this type of input read so even after reading several topics here I still cant find the right way, I have this array to read the 2 bytes

```
char p[2];
```

and this line to read them, of course fopen was called earlier with file pointer fp, I used "rb" as read mode but tried other options too when I noticed this was crashing, Im just saving space and focusing in the trouble itself.

```
fscanf(fp,"%x%x",p[0],p[1]);
```

later to convert into decimal I have this line (if its not the EOF that we reached)

```
v = strtol(p, 0, 10);
```

Well v is mere integer to store the final value we are seeking. But the program keeps crashing when scanf is called or I think thats the case, Im not compiling to console so its a pitty that I cant output what has been done and what hasnt but in debugger it seems like crashing there

Well I hope you can help me out in this, Im a bit lost regarding this type of read/conversion any clue will help me greatly, thanks =).

PS forgot to add that this is not homework, a friend want to make some file conversion for a game and this code will manipulate the files needed alone, so while I could be using any language or environment for this, I always feel better in C language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated*** *byte strings*. That *null-terminated* part is important, as it means a string of two characters needs space for *three* characters to include the null-terminator character `'\0'`. Not having the terminator means string functions will go out of bounds in their search for it, leading to *undefined behavior*.

*Furthermore* the `"%x"` format is to read a heaxadecimal *integer number* and store it in an `int`. Mismatching format specifiers and arguments leads to *undefined behavior*.

Lastly and probably what's causing the crash: The `scanf` family of function expects *pointers* as their arguments. Not providing pointers will again lead to *undefined behavior*.

There are two solutions to the above problems:

1. Going with code similar to what you already use, first of all you must make space for the terminator in the array. Then you need to read two *characters*. Lastly you need to *add* the terminator:

   ```
   char p[3] = { 0 };  // String for two characters, initialized to zero
   // The initialization means that we don't need to explicitly add the terminator

   // Read two characters, skipping possible leading white-space
   fscanf(fp," %c%c",p[0],p[1]);

   // Now convert the string to an integer value
   // The string is in base-16 (two hexadecimal characters)
   v = strtol(p, 0, 16);
   ```
2. Read the hexadecimal value into an *integer* directly:

   ```
   unsigned int v;
   fscanf(fp, "%2x", &v);  // Read as hexadecimal
   ```

The second alternative is what I would recommend. It reads two characters and parses it as a hexadecimal value, and stores the result into the variable `v`. It's important to note that the value in `v` is stored *in binary!* Hexadecimal, decimal or octal are just presentation formats, internally in the computer it will still be stored in binary ones and zeros (which is true for the first alternative as well). To print it as decimal use e.g.

```
printf("%d\n", v);
```

Comment: Option 2 is probably what the OP's tutor had in mind.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", v);` better as `printf("%u\n", v);` although not to important unless on 16-bit machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Some programmer dude, it works perfect like you suggested, well I have to fully integrate with a small code that uses certain graphical library and it conflicts here somewhere so I havent fully implemented what my friend needed for that game but your code and explanation are perfect, and I understood everything, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pass to `fscanf()` the address of a the variable(s) to scan into.

   Also the conversion specifier need to suite the variable provided. In your case those are `char`s. `x` expects an `int`, to scan into  a `char` use the appropriate length modifiers, two times `h` here:

   ```
   fscanf(fp, "%hhx%hhx", &p[0], &p[1]);
   ```
2. `strtol()` expects a C-string as 1st parameter.

   What you pass isn't a C-string, as a C-string ought to be `0`-terminated, which `p` isn't.

   To fix this you could do the following:

   ```
   char p[3];

   fscanf(fp, "%x%x", p[0], p[1]);

   p[2] = '\0';

   long v = strtol(p, 0, 10);
   ```

Comment: That will crash too.

Comment: @buster: Well yes, fixed. Thx, missed this.